# we search Ctrl+Shift+O for searching component , so any shortcut or function?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In developer console we are able to find out any component using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - for searching component ,  so is their any shortcut available for searching function name?

Comment: Just a note, and maybe it's a cultural thing, but many people consider duplicate punctuation quite rude. So when you type `??`, `!!!`, etc. that can rub people the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

`Edit->Search In Files` allows you to perform a full-text search across your metadata. The Developer Console does not offer "jump-to-definition", and as far as I am aware it's not possible to perform a filtered query against `SymbolTable` in the Query Editor.

"Jump-to-definition" is, however, a documented feature of the [Salesforce extensions for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex). Any offline IDE will provide a feature equivalent to Developer Console's "Search In Files", often with more functionality.

Comment: yes i agree , same thing happen after search jump-to-defination is not possible if it is a offline IDE then it can search .

Comment: i did with Edit->Search In Files but not give a proper search for function name .

Comment: any other alternative for search a function name directly from org ??

Comment: Are you asking me to clarify any specific part of my answer?

Comment: Yes , as you comment Edit->Search In Files allows you to perform a full-text search , i tried that as well but for full text it is not accurate search  , partial it gives like for component  name .

Comment: I don't have anything to add, Rahul. Search In Files is what Developer Console offers. If you want something else, you need to use a different tool or IDE.